# Unable to send attachment from Gmail using browser

Tags: gmail, attachments

I want to send PDF, and DOC file using Gmail on Sony Xperia. But there is no option to add attachment on Google Chrome, Firefox or Dolphin. Also, when I open Gmail on stock browser with desktop version, there is an option to add an attachment, but it doesn't actually add the attachment, and only text data is sent. How to send attachment using Gmail on phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, I tried your way just a while ago and I am unable to attach file in Gmail.

If it is possible for you, instead of using Gmail from browser, download [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) app from Play Store and your problem will be solved.